# Is my public IP, the one that I get from Tor, that of an exit relay of that of a bridge when I connect to tor through a bridge?

Tags: exit-relays, bridge

When I connect to Tor through a bridge, is the public IP that the services like websites see [that of an exit relay](https://community.torproject.org/relay/types-of-relays/) or that of a bridge? Is my public IP always that of an exit relay, irrespective of being connected through a bridge or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is the **exit** node's public IP address

Bridges are your first step into the Tor network while exit nodes are your last one. It is the exit nodes that do the requests through the regular Internet (or *clearnet*) on your behalf, so it is **the exit nodes'** IP address the ones the services see.